# How to enable Syntax highlighting on Vim in Mac OS Terminal?

Tags: terminal, macvim

Is there a way to let Vim on Mac OS highlighten syntax of different languages in Terminal? I would guess for vim it is a .vimrc thing, right? (But I cannot find this file in my home folder).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If the file ~/.vimrc is not there, you'll just need to create it. To enable syntax highlighting, add

```
syntax on
```

to it. Also make sure that "Display ANSI colors" is enabled in the Terminal Settings.

Answer (score 1):

You most probably want to enable indentation along with syntax highlighting, so add these to lines to ~/.vimrc

```
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

Steps with screenshots can be found here
http://osxandiosdaily.com/how-to-enable-vim-syntax-highlighting-on-mac-osx/